# Cant reset the mysql-server 5.7.12 root password on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, webserver, ubuntu-14.04

I'am pretty new with linux and installed a webserver. I installed apache2, php7.0 and mysql-server-5.7.12 + phpmyadmin.

Now i try to login to the mysql-server trough phpmyadmin (with the password i typed during the installation of mysql-server) and it says `#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I googled the error but i cant find a WORKING solution. I tryed to reset the root password by reinstalling mysql-server with the folowing commands:

1. sudo su
2. apt-get remove mysql-server
3. apt-get autoremove
4. apt-get clear
5. apt-get update
6. apt-get install mysql-server

This didn't work so i tryed another way to reset the password:
This way is described [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) This also not worked for me.

I tryed [this](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/) also. But also this isn't working for me. I cant come in mysql "prompt" or how it is caled.

I know there are more of the same questions on stackoverflow but these are not working for me......

When i type `mysql -u root` or `mysql -u root -p` in my terminal i get the same error as in php my admin: `https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/`

Hope someone can help me becouse i struggle a while with this problem.....

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: The first link i already tried (see my question). The method described in the second link doesn't work. I can execute the first 2 commands. These are working (stopping the mysql server process) but when execute the `mysql -u root` i get this error message back: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` Offcource i executed the commands as su.

Comment: Then you didn't do the `--skip-grant-tables` part correctly. Perhaps you edited the wrong `my.cnf` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long try and error i fixed the problem. I did this on this way:

1. Running the command `sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-*`
2. running the command `sudo apt-get autoremove

After this my phpMyAdmin had an error that mysqli is missing. 
To fix this i did:

1. sudo apt-get install php-mysql
2. service apache2 restart

The installing the mysql-server. For test purposals i tryed to install mysql-server 5.5 and 5.6 but these had allways installation errors. After executing the folowing commands mysql-server-7.6.12 was installed correctly:

1. cd /home/your-username/Downloads
2. wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
3. sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb
   I set the mysqlserver to `Mysql Server (mysql-5.7)` and tools to `disable`. After this i selected `apply` and executed the following commands:
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get install mysql-server

After this i got a question (don't remember exacly what the questionw was but something with an directory wil be......., i anwered with yes).
After this question i could configure an root password and login to my phpmyadmin.

@Mitch Jackson, Thanks for the answer anyway, it put me in the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The root password is stored in a database table.  Reinstalling mysql with apt-get doesn't remove that table data unless you issue the --purge parameter.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client
```

This is the long way round, but it will get you there.

Comment: This doesnt work. I don't get the "set mysql root password" window. After execute the give commands (with apt-get autoremove between de the 2 commands) won't do the trick. I get this message: `MySQL Community Server 5.7.12 is started
grep: schrijffout: Gebroken pijp
2016-05-19T09:07:38.871082Z mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Instellen van mysql-server (5.7.12-1ubuntu14.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...`